# Keep 10 newest rows eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have eloquent log handler and I want to limit it on newest 10 rows only by deleting the others.

If I try `$model->orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(10)->delete();` when rows count is less than 10 all rows get deleted.

Comment: `if ($model->count() > 10){.. delete stuff}`.

Comment: first time it enters `if()` it deletes all like there is no skip().

Comment: `$model->oldest()->skip(10)->take($model->count()-10)->delete();`

Comment: With `get()` `skip()` is working fine, but as soon I call `->delete()` it deletes all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution but it's not very elegant.

```
    $delete_rows = $model->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->skip(9)->get()->toArray(); 
    $model->whereIn('id', $delete_rows)->delete();
```

Comment: You can simplify first line to this `$model->oldest()->skip(9)->pluck('id')`

Comment: Yes, projection by id with pluck is needed.